# C# regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to fetch the text from line using regex

eg :

```
 string xyz = "text/plain; charset=US-ASCII; name=\"anythingfile.txt\"";
```

and i want to fetch the **anythingfile.txt** from that line

that mean i want to create regex that match the pattern **name=""** and fetch string between double quotes
I tried with this

```
regex re= new regex(@"name="\"[\\w ]*\""")
```

but not getting proper result ....plz help me.

Comment: Might be easier if you use a regular string literal rather than verbatim, since you need to do escaping anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this Regex Pattern,

```
(?<=name="").*(?="")
```

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Perfect Thanks a lot.... could you plz suggest me how/where to learn regualr expressions?

Comment: I sometimes use [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) to figure out complex expressions

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need regex? Simple string operations may be enough:

```
var NameValue = xyz.Split(';')
                   .Select(x => x.Split('='))
                   .ToDictionary(y => y.First().Trim(), y => y.LastOrDefault());
```

Comment: you r making it too complex. also op never said that it would end with `;`

Comment: These are not 'simple' string operations, you are running a whole query on the string ;)

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It is most probably from Http Headers and I also never assumed it would end with `;` But `;` is a separator char.

Comment: @WouterH Split+Linq that is all.

Comment: A benchmark: 1000000 times using my regex example: 2171ms, 1000000 times your simple solution: 11973ms. Auch!

Comment: @WouterH if I needed speed I would use `int inx = xyz.LastIndexOf('='); var fname = xyz.Substring(inx + 2, xyz.Length - inx - 3);`

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to use a named group:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string xyz = "text/plain; charset=US-ASCII; name=\"anythingfile.txt\"";
        Match m = Regex.Match(xyz, "name=\"(?<name>[^\"]+)\"");
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["name"].Value);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```